# Drupal-7 + zen cart

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, zen-cart

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate zen cart to Drupal 7+ ?
I know that there was a Drupal zen cart integration project http://drupal.org/project/zencart
but it seems only support in Drupal 5.x

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's very unlikely, efforts for e-commerce in Drupal 7 have been very firmly moved into the [Commerce module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) which is still a wee bit unstable and without a full complement of add-ons as yet.

There's also the [Ubercart module](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) which as it happens I'm grappling with myself at the moment. It's fairly complete but be prepared to get stuck in and do some coding if you want it to do anything that's not 'out-of-the-box'.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is great as long as it is not fully ecommerce. If the site has content plus little bit of selling, then drupal is OK. If you are serious about online shopping for your site, then magneto or a paid software might be a solution.

Magneto is not totally free, the free one is not easy and it is slow.

I have experienced zencart and it is OK if you are going to use it as the main cart integrated with forum or content management systems, the integration is not always easy. zencart is badly designed for a framework point of view, examples, inserting inline css in the template doesn't allow flexibility in overriding especially if the markup output is the result of a module.

I would generally prefer to use drupal for CMS/social network, zencart for online shop, phpbb for forums.

I chose zencart because I am an experienced web developer and I can work around badly designed table-based module output. The main templates are easy to edit. check http://domainpiranha.com/customizezencart.

It is the case in all CMS framework that you have to deal with them the way they are. If you are willing to extensively customize, then programming your own software might be easier.

Comment: Drupal has many users who contributes with patches, or bug reports. If you are writing your software which will have at least half the contributors Drupal has, then you are good. Drupal.org has also a security team, which investigate on Drupal security issues (including ones exposed from third-party modules hosted on Drupal.org); if your software is not going to have a security team, then it is probable it is less secure.